# Regex to find first occurence of a character in lines matching a character

Tags: regex

I am trying to do find and replace in my eclipse workspace on all properties files. The condition is that I have to find the lines which has the character '<' and then get the first matching "=" character on those matched lines.

For example

```
app.searchform.height.label=Height <b>(in cm)</b>
```

I want to find the char `=` in the above line and replace it with like `=<has_html>` so I get the below output

```
app.searchform.height.label=<has_html>Height <b>(in cm)</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:
`^(.*?)=(?=.*<)`

With this as the replacement string:
`$1=<has_html>`

[Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/40h7e9/2)

Explanation:
In order to limit matches to 1 per line I start the match at the beging of the line with `^`
Then uses a lazy quantifier to expand out words, stuffing everything into a capture group to paste back in later with `(.*?)`
then terminate the expansion o a `=` character and use a lookahead `(?=.*<)` to check for the `<` character

Comment: Thanks @doom87er. Worked perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex,

```
(?=.*<)=
```

And replace it with,

```
=<has_html>
```

Explanation: Positive look ahead ensures the replacement only occurs if it finds < character in the string. And then just matches with = and replaces it with =< has_html>.

Demo,
https://regex101.com/r/yLt9j4/1

Edit1:
Here is how you can do it in java codes for replacing only first occurrence of =,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "app.searchform.height.label=Height <b>(in =cm)</b>";

    System.out.println("Before: " + s);
    s = s.replaceFirst("(?=.*<)=", "=<has_html>");
    System.out.println("After: " + s);
}
```

This gives following output,

```
Before: app.searchform.height.label=Height <b>(in =cm)</b>
After: app.searchform.height.label=<has_html>Height <b>(in =cm)</b>
```

Comment: Thanks. Working almost perfect. How can I restrict it to just find only the first occurence of character `=` in a line? This is finding all the occurences of `=` in lines having `<`

Comment: For a pure regex solution, one of the ways doom87er has already posted another answer. But you can achieve this easily in your language also. My main language is java so updating my answer with codes in java. At least I know you can do similar thing in python as I did once long time back.